# Error "ImportError: cannot import name '_get_object_size' from 'bson' "

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

when running the below file , I am getting error "ImportError: cannot import name '*get_object_size' from 'bson' (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bson_*init**.py)"

code:
`from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
# from bson.objectid import ObjectId

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = connectionstring
mongo = PyMongo(app)

# Create a new to-do item
@app.route('/api/todo', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    # data = request.json

    # Create a new to-do item in the database
 new_todo = {
        # 'task': data['task'],
        # 'due_date': data['due_date'],
        # 'completed': False
        "task": "study",
        "date": 18,
        "completed": False
    }

 result = mongo.db.todos.insert_one(new_todo)
 print(result,"has been created")`
```

I am creating a todo list using flask environment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

uninstall both pymongo and bson
and install just pymongo, pymongo automatically installs bson

```
pip uninstall pymongo
```

```
pip uninstall bson
```

```
pip install pymongo
```