# MongoDB delete document using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I am trying to delete document from MongoDB using python and there are error. I install `pymongo` and `bson`

```python
from pymongo import MongoClient
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from connections import db_password

encoded_password = quote_plus(db_password)

cluster = MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://nazarworker17:{encoded_password}@cluster0.momxsd3.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = cluster["test"]
collection = db["test"]


my_document = {"name":"Nazar"}

collection.delete_one(my_document)
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_object_size' from 'bson'
```

Comment: Is there a file in your current directory named `bson.py`?

Comment: Isn't the proper `bson` module installed with `pymongo`?  Maybe there is a conflict if you installed some other `bson` module.

Comment: check this one out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321221/error-importerror-cannot-import-name-get-object-size-from-bson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "ImportError: cannot import name '\_get\_object\_size' from 'bson' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321221/error-importerror-cannot-import-name-get-object-size-from-bson)

Comment: i just unistall both lib and install pymongo , thanks all